# When should i require function from global space?

Tags: php

I am trying to understand the reason to require a function from a global space.

Example from PHP manual:

```
namespace A\B\C;

/* This function is A\B\C\fopen */
function fopen() { 
     /* ... */
     $f = \fopen(...); // call global fopen
     return $f;
}
```

In which case or why would i require a function from a global space like in this example? can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `A\B\C` namespace call to `fopen` will be resolved in this namespace. Hence, without explicitly specified global namespace, the call will lead to infinite recursion:

```
function fopen() { 
  $f = fopen(...);  // ERROR RECURSIVE CALL TO ITSELF
  $f = \A\B\C\fopen(...);  // ERROR THE SAME AS ABOVE
  $f = \fopen(...); // call global fopen ⇛ WORKS
```

Please note, that there is no necessity to explicitly specify global namespace if *there is no function with this name in current namespace*.